# Fastest Multimodal sampler

Tags: sampling, multimodality

I am currently working with Multinest, a bayesian multimodal sampler however it becomes slow for higher dimensions, exponentially slow.

Is there another sampler out there that can give me parameter values from chi squared minimization of a multimodal distribution?

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi there and welcome. Could you provide a hyperlink to `Multinest`?

Comment: Thank you! These are the links for: https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/MultiNest and https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3437.pdf